# How to pause and resume AsyncTask or change order of Asynctask execution in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am using Asynctask to get data from the net. When the application starts it refreshes data from the internet. I now included an option to autocomplete when "adding new things" which retrieves matching strings from internet. The problem is when "adding new things" the matching string is not fetched instantaneously when typed instead it waits for refreshing to first complete. So I want to pause the refreshing thread for a while, while I am "adding new things" or just some other way to fetch matching string instantaneously. I looked at other answer but some were not working some were not what I wanted. Help me overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch another AsyncTask like this:

new AsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

This will launch it on a separate thread from the first asynctask. I actually suggest launching all tasks like this since then they will all be on different threads.